Back Transforming log-log Model for Prediction
I have a model that is log-log and I would like to make raw predictions of $Y$ with it:
$\ln(Y) = B_0 + B_1\ln(X)$
All answers and articles I have found concerning back transforming for prediction only deal with semi-log models:
either $Y \sim B_0 + B_1 \ln(X)$ or $\ln(Y) \sim B_0 + B_1X $
I have seen Duan's Smear, but does this apply to log-log models as well?
I'm looking to move from percentages to actual $Y$ predictions.

If your model says $\ln(\hat Y) = B_0 + B_1\ln(X)$ then this is equivalent to $\hat Y = e^{B_0} X^{B_1}.$  If your model is unbiased for $\ln(\hat Y)$ then it is going to be biased for $\hat Y$, but that is not necessarily a bad thing - it is a consequence of your model.

@dimitriy When you say "wrong" you seem to be worried about "biased" which I mentioned in my earlier comment.  Simple linear regression passes through the arithmetic mean of the observations; if instead a log-log model is a sensible approach, it seems reasonable to me that you instead get something going through the geometric mean of the original data. If that is, in your view, "wrong" or a bad thing, then perhaps you should not be using a log-log model.

Duan's approach applies to logged outcome models, as does the normal approximation described here.
It does not matter whether the covariates are logged, except insofar as you will need to calculate $\ln X$ before multiplying by $\hat B_1$.

@OberonQuinn If this answers your question, you can select it as the answer!
